# How would I check the version of vncserver on Redhat?

Tags: linux, vnc, redhat-enterprise-linux, vncserver

I want to check which version of vncserver I am using in my linux box. What is the command for that?

When I run

```
which vncserver
```

I get

```
/usr/bin/vncserver
```

P.S: I am running Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.8 (Tikanga)

Answer (score 4):

Use this command

```
rpm -qa | grep tigervnc-server
```

Answer (score 2):

To find out from what package (and version) a file comes, you can do `rpm -qf /usr/bin/vncserver`, see the manual for rpm(1). But note that RHEL (as do all enterprisey distributions) selects a base version, and keep that one whatever may come during the RHEL 5.x series in this particular case. The base software is patched with backports for new features (where relevant), bug fixes and whatnot. So don't be surprised if you see a version reported that won the all-time CVE popularity contest, what you are running is *not* that one.

Check the reports for RHEL updates, I believe they either send them to all users, are available on a (read-only) mailing list, and on their website.